# command line mail client with crm functionality

Tags: mysql, vim, emacs, crm

I've been using various SaaS solutions for CRM together with my google apps mail. However, the workflow is just to slow, and I'm looking to switch to a solution where I can use more keyboard shortcuts and work faster. I need to lookup email conversations and update CRM records.

So I thought about switching to a terminal mail client with rich keyboard shortcuts, which I could also extend to talk to a mysql database.

What would be the best solution for this? I thought about emacs, but I've never used it. I use vim regularly, but I'm not sure if extending that to read email and access mysql DBs is pushing it.

I'm on mac osx.

Thanks
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much time you want to invest. Given enough time, desire, and willpower, you could do something like this:

1. Write a command-line (or maybe a private web API) to handle some of the CRM tasks, like adding a note to a contact, flagging them as something else, or whatever else you do. This would just handle doing *something* with an email address in your CRM, but it wouldn't handle messages themselves. Probably a night/day's worth of work for some basic functionality.
2. Once you determine which mail client you're going to use, write some small bindings around the mail mode. I would personally choose Emacs because you could easily write a function to extract the email address from your message (or current buffer) and do some CRM command (via #1) with it. Emacs has some nice mail clients like mu4e and GNUS, so it'd integrate nicely. It'd also be simple in Vim too, but Emacs+evil-mode+(mu4e|GNUS) is a pretty good combination.

The advantage of this solution is you're only investing a minimal amount of effort into #2 -- these would be simple "get email address, call script" functions -- so you could switch from Emacs to another client without too much pain. You could even switch between mail clients within Emacs!

Comment: cool, this sounds like what I need - however I never used emacs before ... what if I want to open a photo attachment from emacs on mac osx? is there a way to send the attachments to preview, the viewer on mac ?

Comment: @b20000: In Emacs, you can actually view images and PDFs inside the viewer if you're running it with a GUI. [mu4e](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e.html) looks like it does a good job with attachments. It uses OS X's `open` program to open the attachment in whatever OS X default to. You can also view images inline too. You can do the same in GNUS too. I should clarify too: I haven't used either of these clients for more than testing -- it's on my TODO list to switch from Gmail. For choosing a client, my vote goes to mu4e for it's rich text formatting option (and thinner manual).

Comment: thanks, what is the recommended package manager to install this? brew?

Comment: @b20000: For Emacs on OS X, I would just grab [this custom Emacs build](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port). It's way faster at running remote shells, spell checkers, and other remote processes (and has some nice GUI features too). You can do it with Homebrew -- there's a recipe there -- but I just use the binary from the downloads page. Inside of Emacs, you can use `M-x package-list-packages` to browse add-ons too.

Comment: cool, thanks! where would i go to learn some basics coming from vim... and to write my first addon so I can get the email address from the email, connect to mysql and do something with it ?

Comment: @b20000: [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/reading-guide/) has a great page for getting started with Emacs. If you're coming from Vim, you should grab `evil-mode` (M-x package-install evil-mode). It's Vim keys (not Vi) in Emacs. I'm coming from a Vim background, and after years of doing things with Emacs chords, I've finally switched back. For grabbing the email address, research regular expressions in Emacs (quirky like Vim's). Once you have that, just pass that over to a standalone CLI program with a shell call.

Comment: For Elisp itself, you can always do `C-h a RET whatever-you-want` or if you see a function, just hit `C-h f RET function-name` to get documentation. The manual is built-in and also available [online](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html). The best advice is to just play around with the `*scratch*` buffer!

Comment: still not clear to me which mac emacs version I should use if I also want to use mu4e ... ? the only emacs that seemed to install easily is the one I can install through homebrew but it doesn't seem very mac specific, and I need something that has attachment viewing working out of the box ...

Comment: This is getting into Superuser territory (and a really long SO comment thread). I don't use mu4e, but my stab is: `brew install emacs --cocoa` followed by `brew install mu --with-emacs`. Then following along with [mu4e's manual](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Getting-started.html#Getting-started) to set it up.

Comment: I installed emacs - turns out it is version 24.2. Install went fine. But then I got this: sudo brew install mu --with-emacs
Emacs 23 or greater is required to build this software.

Comment: @b20000: Did you install Emacs through Homebrew?